# Storing values in a particular format in the array, which are retrieved from a .csv file to the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

An attribute from a .csv file which looks like:

```
[[-8.585676,41.148522],[-8.585712,41.148639],[-8.585685,41.148855]]
```

I want to split this data into an 2D array USING PHP, which I want to look like this:

```
arr[0][0] = -8.585676
arr[0][1] = 41.148522

arr[1][0] = -8.585712
arr[1][1] = -41.148639

arr[2][0] = -8.585685
arr[2][1] = 41.148855
```

I have done it like this:

```
$arr = preg_split('[,]', $str);
    $n = count($arr);
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        echo $arr[$i];

        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
```

Its output looks like:

```
[[-8.585676
41.148522]
[-8.585712
41.148639]
[-8.585685
41.148855]
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happens to be a perfect match for a `json_decode()` call. Simply use `$arr = json_decode($str);` and it'll do the trick.